# How to check the history of package versions in virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I want to know what was the previous version of package that was installed in my vitrualenv before I have upgraded it.
Lets say I have `lib==1.1.0` then I upgrade it using `pip install upgrade lib==1.2.0` and after that I want to check what was the previous version (`1.1.0`)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that (but I'd be interested to see if someone proves me wrong). However, if you want to keep track of what packages were installed at various stages of a project and you're a user of `git`, simply `git freeze > requirements.txt` and add that to your repo.

Comment: Definitely thats the right approach when developing, but it was during testing, and i want to be sure to get back to the exact last version that was installed in my venv.

Answer (score -1):

> what was the previous version of package that was installed in my vitrualenv

Unfortunaltey, a virtualenv does not keep track of changes made to it.

As @Grismar pointed out, you may "freeze" the list of all installed packages, and then re-install to the previous set at a later point:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt   
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I don't want all available libraries from online repository. I want the last version that was installed on my machine.

Comment: @MateuszDorobek thanks for the feedback,updated the answer